# How to download and save BLOB data to local storage through DolphinDB Python API?

Tags: python, blob, dolphindb

When I save a table with PROTOCOL_PICKLE, an error occurs: `Server response: 'pickle not support BLOB. IP[]. uuid[]. int128[]'`.

The following is my script:

```
t = loadTable("dfs://GILDATA.LC_ANNOUNCEMENT", `data)
select * from t where companycode = '187163' and category = 4 order by infopubldate desc limit 100
//result from the API
￵{"emojiDesc":"","emojiUrl":"","hasSourceImage":false,"hashCode":17223055,"height":73,"srcPath":"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.tencent.wework/files/imagecache/imagemsg2/5/5dbd98da0d44bff89f48882dfa38366d.0","thumbPath":"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.tencent.wework/files/imagecache/imagemsg2/6/6815099d982e9c4fef058ea1c5494bbd.0","width":1130,"wwFileId":""}￰
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROTOCOL_PICKLE does not support some special data types. You can modify it to the PROTOCOL_DDB when creating the session (by specifying `enablePickle=False` or `protocol=keys.PROTOCOL_DDB`).